# Office 2010: Download features now, not on demand

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2010

Office 2010 (the trial version, home and student edition) tries to download features when I use them the first time (e.g. Hyphenation). Is there a way to tell it to download certain/all features now, so I have them later when I am without internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to the MSI-based version [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/click-to-run-switch-to-using-an-msi-based-office-edition-HA101850538.aspx).

Comment: Good to know for next time. Now I just told my friend who hat this problem to use every feature she needed offline once instead :-).